# How to get a switch to recognize upper and lower case characters?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to use a switch with a character as the expression.
I keep getting an error that I have a duplicate case label. I am assuming this is due to the fact that I have 'c' and 'C'. One is lower case and one is upper case. I thought switch was case sensitive.
Here is my code:

```
switch(n)
{
  case 'f':
    if(n == 'f')
  System.out.println("--" + n + "--");
else
  System.out.println("-----");
break;

  case 'e':
if(n == 'e')
  System.out.println("  " + n + "  ");
else
  System.out.println("     ");
break;

  case 'd':
if(n == 'd')
  System.out.println("--" + n + "--");
else
  System.out.println("-----");
break;

  case 'c':
if(n == 'c')
  System.out.println("  " + n + "  ");
else
  System.out.println("     ");
break;

case 'B':
if(n == 'B')
  System.out.println("--" + n + "--");
else
  System.out.println("-----");
break;

case 'A':
if(n == 'A')
  System.out.println("  " + n + "  ");
else
  System.out.println("     ");
break;

case 'G':
if(n == 'G')
  System.out.println("--" + n + "--");
else
  System.out.println("-----");
break;

case 'F':
if(n == 'F')
  System.out.println("  " + n + "  ");
else
  System.out.println("     ");
break;

case 'E':
if(n == 'E')
  System.out.println("--" + n + "--");
else
  System.out.println("-----");
break;

case 'D':
if(n == 'D')
  System.out.println("  " + n + "  ");
else
  System.out.println("     ");
break;

case 'C':
if(n == 'C')
  System.out.println("--" + n + "--");
else
  System.out.println("-----");
break;

}//end switch
```

I want upper c and lower case c to be different cases.

How can I fix this issue and get the switch to recognize that c and C are different?

Comment: Your assumption is not correct. Java knows the difference between upper and lower case.

Comment: Could you report the exact error you are getting? Your code compiles and runs without any problem

Comment: [The code you posted doesn't give an error](https://ideone.com/gDYwDg). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Note that `if(n == 'f')` after `case 'f':` is entirely unnecessary (since it will always be true) if you're `break`ing at the end of every case (or was that just test code?).

Comment: @Sneftel . You are right. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all of yalls help. For some odd reason, i was getting the error but then I reopened my compiler and it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

you are switching character 'n', I don't see the reason you should put if statement inside the case. For instance in your code, I picked a section

```
 case 'e':
if(n == 'e')
  System.out.println("  " + n + "  ");
else
  System.out.println("     ");
break;
```

you see case 'e' is already telling that block that if the switch is e, which means you if-else is a repetition. Look at a simple code I made and it runs well.

```
public class MyClass {
   static char choice='a';
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     switch(choice)
{
    case 'A': 
          System.out.println("The big a");
         break;
    case 'a':
          System.out.println("The small a");
         break;
    case 'C':
          System.out.println("The Third Letter of the Alphabet");
         break;
}


    }
}
```

*Try editing you code by removing the if else statements like my code above. I will be around to give a different approach if you are not happy with this answer*